# Many To Many Relationship in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many, one-to-many

There are two tables in a database.

The first table is "users". It has two columns. A user_id column and a sector_id column.

- It is possible for a user to follow multiple sectors. Which would lead to the user_id appearing in multiple rows but with a differ sector_id
- It is possible for the same sector be be followed by different users. Which would lead to the sector_id appearing in multiple rows but with a differ user_id

Eaxample:

| user_id | sector_id |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 123 |
| user1 | 234 |
| user2 | 453 |
| user2 | 123 |

The second table is "articles". It has two columns. An article_id column and a sector_id column.

- It is possible for different articles to have the same sector.

Eaxample:

| article_id | sector_id |
| --- | --- |
| article1 | 123 |
| article2 | 234 |
| article3 | 453 |
| article4 | 123 |

---

I want to find out how many articles are available for each user. An article is available for a user if the user follows the sector of the article.

I thought of doing a join on the sector_id. But since many users and many articles can share the same sector_id, not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

Comment: You make a bridge table

Comment: Why not try it and see if it gives the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many "bridge" tables as needed, one per each relationship between that pair of tables.

For example:

```
create table users (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

create table sectors (
  id int primary key not null,
  name varchar(20) not null
);

create table following (
  user_id int not null references users (id),
  sector_id int not null references sectors (id)
  , primary key (user_id, sector_id) -- optional, if applicable
);
```